# SVG as background Image, cross browser compatibility

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

While using SVG as background image, if I need to fit the image correctly, then have to specify separate background positions for different browsers.

Is it the way I experienced, or I am doing something wrong.

The CSS I am trying to use:

```
.some {
  background: transparent url('some.png') no-repeat -X1px -Y1px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('some.svg') no-repeat -X2px -Y2px;
  width: 53px;
  height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything specific that's not working? Or are you just generally asking if this is a good cross-browser method?

Comment: Well the same background-position is not working for all the browsers, have to tweak background-positon for every other browser.
Never had this issue while working with a PNG sprite as background .

Comment: Is the svg scale/size causing the issue? If so, the below 2 answers should help.

Comment: background size on a svg sprite ?

Comment: This is scaling the svg sprite.
400X1500 sprite scaled to 53X14, was that the intention ?

Comment: Was that not what you were looking for when you said "fitting the image correctly"? If not, please explain in more detail what the problem is or create a JSFiddle showing the problem.

Comment: pardon my english, but I was pointing to the offset(background-position), that one has to specify when using a sprite.
The offsets are different for chrome, firefox and IE9, while using SVG sprites.

Comment: How about cropping your svg to the image you need, and simply using "top center" or so as position?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG sprite background-position crossbrowser variations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076655/svg-sprite-background-position-crossbrowser-variations)

Comment: Answer can be found here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076655/svg-sprite-background-position-crossbrowser-variations/19108392#19108392

Answer (score -1):

How are you trying to apply your background image to your html document?

It should just work if you use:

```
background-cover:cover;
```

not sure why you would position the BG like that.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: You mean positon:relative ?

Comment: It's hard to understand the context without seeing your html. There are several ways I might do this, but if you have a really complex SVG browser support is still not there across the board.

Answer (score -1):

To scale your svg background, you can use:

```
background-size: 53px 14px;
```