# SVG sprite background-position crossbrowser variations

Tags: css, svg

This is a repost
[SVG as background Image, cross browser compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443331/svg-as-background-image-cross-browser-compatibility)

Since I feel the I didn't get an answer because my question was ambiguous, i am posting this again.

I have an issue with offset(background-position) of a svg sprite as different in different browsers.
Apparently the offset needs to be adjusted for different browsers. i.e.

```
//Chrome Safari
.some{
      background: transparent url('some.png') no-repeat -X1px -Y1px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('some.svg') no-repeat -X2px -Y2px;
      width: 53px;
      height: 14px;
      position: relative;
      top: 13px;
      left: 30px;
}
//Mozilla
.some:not(:-moz-handler-blocked){
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('some.svg') no-repeat -X2px (-Y2+4)px;
}
 /IE9
.ie9 .some {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('some.svg') no-repeat -X2px (-Y2+8)px;
}
```

So this way, adjustments need to be made for Y offset.

And  often the offsets are different for different background images in the sane sprite for the same browser.
Is there an easier way out of this?

Comment: These `-X1px -Y1px` are not vanilla CSS3, is it? If you use a precompiler (SASS, LESS, etc.) you should mark it in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some hit and trial, found out that one needs to give background-size to your background css.
This will lead to the background-position being same for all the browsers.

```
.some{
    background: transparent url('some.png') no-repeat -X1px -Y1px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('some.svg') no-repeat -X2px -Y2px;
    width: 53px;
    height: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: 30px;
    background-size:sizeXpx sizeYpx;
}
```